# Angular.js - Filtrar um array numa tabela com base no input do utilizador - HTML

Tags: html, angularjs

Eu quero fazer uma tabela em que as `td` são o nome e o preço de um item. E quero que o utilizador consiga procurar um item pelo seu nome através de um `input`. Isso já está a funcionar. Mas a tabela não está a aparecer como eu quero, pois eu insiro o array num único `td` e fico apenas com uma linha de items, enquanto que eu quero uma coluna. 
Eu tenho assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quero que os nomes apareçam em coluna e não em linha. O meu código é:

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">
            <p>Pesquise um menu</p>
            <p><input type="text" ng-model="test"></p>
    </form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Preço</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="myTable">
                    <tr>
                        <td ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">{{ x }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

script:

```
<script>
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('namesCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.names = [
            'Jani',
            'Carl',
            'Margareth',
            'Hege',
            'Joe',
            'Gustav',
            'Birgit',
            'Mary',
            'Kai'
        ];
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta mudar isso aqui:

```
<tr>
    <td ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">{{ x }}</td>
</tr>
```

para

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter:test">
    <td>{{ x }}</td>
</tr>
```

Ao criar o `ng-repeat` no `td`, você repete a coluna e não o `tr` (linha)